# ACF Relationship Previous Next links of CPT

Tags: php, wordpress, relationship, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

Despite what I’ve read and found here and elsewhere, I’m still having trouble figuring out how to get prev/next posts to work with relationship fields on a site and I was hoping for some guidance.

I have a CPT for artworks with custom taxonomy for artists. Then I have another CPT for artists. The artist pages are basically the the page title (artist name) and a relationship field where you add the artist’s artwork from the artworks CPT where you can filter by the custom taxonomy (since there are 50+ artists and 100s of artworks).

Each artwork is its own page as mentioned. When you click on the artwork from an artist page, we want to have the option of going to the next or previous artwork based on the order displayed on the artist page as determined by the order you set from its relationship field. However, the way I have it set now, it obviously just navigates the loop based on the taxonomy and post date as opposed to the order set by the relationship field on the artist page.

```
<div class="previous-post-link">
  <?php previous_post_link('%link', '<div class="prev-link"><i class="fas fa-caret-left"></i></div>', $in_same_term = true, $excluded_terms = '', $taxonomy = 'assignedartist'); ?>
</div>
<div class="next-post-link">
  <?php next_post_link('%link', '<div class="next-link"><i class="fas fa-caret-right"></i></div>', $in_same_term = true, $excluded_terms = '', $taxonomy = 'assignedartist'); ?>
</div>
```

For some reason, I can’t wrap my head around how to query from the single-artist.php (“artist” post type) to the single-artwork.php (“artwork” post type — relationship field, “artworks” ) page and relationship field so I can create Previous and Next links to navigate between artworks. I can manage to pull the page info like title (artist name) but not the relationship field or its order.

I reviewed this post, [Next post in relationship field](https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/next-post-in-relationship-field/) and pages like, [ACF Relationship Field Prev/Next Buttons](https://www.jonathandempsey.dev/journal/acf-relationship-field-prev-next-buttons/), but their setups are just different enough that I get lost. The latter seems to be limited to a single page, but I have several artist pages. The artwork needs to navigate only the artworks featured on whichever artist page it appears. I also feel like the latter would work but I get stuck on the first part in how to pull from all artist pages or the single-artist.php template as opposed to just the page ID in…

```
// This should be the ID of the page the relationship field is set up on,
// NOT this page’s ID
$page_id = 5;

// Get the projects from the relationship field
$project_listing = get_field('project_listing', $page_id);
```

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The relationship is many-to-many, not many-to-one, that is important to understand. Your implementation _might happen to be_ many-to-one, but that is just coincidence. This means _Alice_ might have relations to _Alpha_ and _Bravo_, but technically _Bob_ could have relations to _Bravo_ and _Charlie_. This means when we're on _Bravo_, WordPress doesn't know what "next" should be because both Alice and Bob have references to it. If you happen to have a many-to-one, however, the solution is to find the parent from the child page and iterate over the fields to determine the order.

Comment: [This post](https://alijafarian.com/tutorial/how-to-create-previous-and-next-posts-with-advanced-custom-fields/) which is the answer at the bottom of your second link does the above, as far as I can tell.

Comment: So then would my only choice be to add a relationship field on each artworks CPT to the artist CPT so it knows which page to reference specifically? In other words, since the artworks CPT is just a bunch of pages that coincidentally have artist name taxonomy, the artists CPT is pulling from that general pool of all artworks. Just because I place specific artworks on a specific artist page doesn't eliminate the fact that all artworks can be added to any, several, or all artist pages.

Comment: There's a couple of ways to cheat this. You could pass the artist ID in the URL that gets rendered on `single-artwork.php`, but that is pretty hacky and error prone. You could also create a bidirectional relationship using something [WP-P2P](https://wordpress.org/plugins/posts-to-posts/) however that is no longer maintained. You could also do what you said, manually create a second relationship on the child back to the parent, but that will become cumbersome very fast.

Comment: The last way is to use a [version of this code](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/querying-relationship-fields/), where `$doctors` is your artists, and `get_field('photo', $doctor->ID)` is the artist's artwork. You should be able to loop over that artwork, find the current artwork you are on, and determine previous/next from that. This is the path that I would recommend.

Comment: Chris, this is quite an education and even though I have a loose grasp of you final recommendation, I feel on the right path now and I can't tell you how much I appreciate it. Thank you for the quick responses. The last recommendation seems more of what I was thinking was possible. I was also wondering if were possible to somehow leverage the artist taxonomy that comes with the artworks CPT but also pulling from that artist's specific CPT.

Comment: Once you determine the WordPress IDs for the parent and child, it is pretty easy. Almost all WordPress functions that start with `wp_get_XXX` or `get_XXX` accept an optional post ID, including [`wp_get_post_terms`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_post_terms/), so you should be able to do pretty much everything. Any of the functions that start with `the_XXX` are generally intended to be run "in the loop" and might not behave as you expect. Some support an ID, some don't. But if you check the docs, they are almost always backed by a `get_XXX` version

Comment: You were right that the one link I added originally seems to be on the right track but there's an issue in how to determine the current post and I can't get that resolved sadly.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried many solutions but none have worked yet. The only way I even get a hint of success is by adding a ACF field to the artworks post type that selects the artist post type via a post object field. As @chris-haas suggested, that hint was found via [This Link](https://alijafarian.com/tutorial/how-to-create-previous-and-next-posts-with-advanced-custom-fields/)

There seems to be an issue with the following code. I'm note sure how $current_post_id applies to the array_search. If I print_r $current_index nothing appears. Same goes for $prev_module and $next_module. However, if I print_r $module_ids the array appears as it should. $first_module and $last_module show the correct IDs too. I just can't seem to get the current post ID to then detemine next and previous.

```
// create empty array for module ids
$module_ids = array();
             
// loop through modules and add them to array
foreach( $modules as $module ) :
    $module_ids[] = $module->ID;
endforeach;
             
// get the current index
$current_index = array_search( $current_post_id, $module_ids );
             
// find the prev/next items
$prev_module = $current_index - 1;
$next_module = $current_index + 1;
             
// find first and last modules
$first_module = $module_ids[0];
$last_module = end($module_ids);
```

I'm a bit at a loss.

Answer (score 0):

For those that come searching for answers facing a similar issue as me. It ended up being as simple as adding the below line before getting the current index.

```
$current_post_id = get_the_ID();
```